# Issue when moving a very old XMLRAD IIS app to another server

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, msxml

We are trying to move a very old XMLRAD IIS HR application from a dead windows 2003 server to a new server.

I'm in the sysadmin team and there is no developper knowing XMLRAD technology in our teams anymore.

We have the app directory with the compiled DLL and XML/XSL files but we feel that we might need additional libraries to make the application work :

- MSXML4 : reinstalled OK
- Dotnet 1.1 : reinstalled OK
- IIS dotnet 1.1 app pool : OK (32 bits applications allowed)
- XMLRAD DLL registered as an ISAPI extension and allowed : OK
- TLB files : recovered and put in same directory than DLL. No app error anymore
- Oracle client : OK. No app error anymore
- Application launch : OK Trace file populated
- Application connection to database : OK (checked with wireshark)
- BUT we have an XMLCursor issue after the database call with the application trying to load additional libraries/dll

Are we missing something ? Help would be very appreciated to help us on this old technology.

Comment: Probably best posted on [sf] or Reddit

Comment: You do need a .NET developer to take a look at the code base and the error itself, so as to tell what might be wrong. However, that's just impossible over a site like this. Hire an experienced consultant or find someone inside your company to help please.